# Proving intersections within a $\sigma$-field is a $\sigma-$field

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $\varOmega$ be a sample space and let $F$ be a $\sigma$-field of subsets of $\varOmega$ and suppose that $\phi \neq B \in F$. Prove that $G = {(A \cap B : A \in F)}$ is a G-field of subsets of B.

My attempt:
Show $\phi \in G.$

Let $A = \phi$, then $\phi \cap B = \phi \in G$.

Show $(A \cap B)^{c} \in G$
I am struggling with proving this property.

Show $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i \cap B  \in G$
$\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \cap B = (\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i) \cap B$. Since $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \in F$, $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \cap B \in G$

This is what I have for this proof. Some help with proving the complement would be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$B \setminus (A \cap B)=B \cap A^c \in G$ since $A^c \in F$

Comment: But how is $ B \cap A^c \in G$ ? I don't understand. We're trying to find $(A \cap B)^c$, why are we using $B$ \ $(A \cap B)$ ?

Comment: $A^c$ belongs to $F$..so the complement with respect  to $B$ (since we have to prove that $G$ is a sigma algebra of subsets  of $B$,not of $\Omega$ )..is a set of the form $B \cap C$ where $C$ belongs to $F$

Comment: Right I see now. The hiccup was not considering that G is a sigma algebra of subsets of B, not $\varOmega$. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You are welcome . You can find a counterexample as an exercise to prove that it not need to be a sigma algebra of subsets of  $\Omega$.